# How to count table-cell that generates by AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sum

I have an angular table that generates by JSON data,
and I'm trying to workout with the JSON data to get total of each column..

Anyone has idea or workaround on this idea?
I thought to iterate to each array, but don't know how..

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {


    var data = {
        "tableName":[{
            "name": "Data Name 1",
            "price" : 20
        },{
            "name": "Data Name 2",
            "price" : 30
        }]
    };

    $scope.datas = data.tableName;
    $scope.results = 50; //<-- Calculate the price value of the tableName

}
```

Here is the sample link: http://jsfiddle.net/Rycode/aMhPq/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/AZN39/

```
 $scope.results =   getTotal();



    function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.datas, function (data) {
        total += data.price
    })

    return total;

}
```

Comment: Great! that's the exactly what I need!